# _ref is undefiend when using react-router-dom's Navlink component

Tags: react-router-dom

While setting up a new react web app project, and after installing `react-router-dom` v^6.8.0, the moment I used `NavLink` imported from `react-router-dom` like so:

```js
<NavLink>
  <MyCustomJsx />
</NavLink>
```

The app would crash saying:

`Unexpected Application Error! _ref is undefined`

After checking the console:

`React Router caught the following error during render TypeError: _ref is undefined`, and in a different, second log: `The above error occurred in the <Link> component: Stacktrace here`

Googling this yielded nothing, as there are so many posts and questions about react's ref, the HTML ref being undefined but not about this underscore-ref: `_ref`. Removing the `<NavLink>` gets rid of the error... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After messing around for a while, by accident, I provided the `to` prop to `NavLink` with a string value like this:

```js
<NavLink to="/downloads">
  <MyCustomJsx />
</NavLink>
```

then the error disappeared and the app started. So `_ref` is undefined when you don't provide the `to` prop I guess.